# Unable to install python3.5-dev in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-22.04

I have installed Python 3.5 from the source using altinstall. I am trying to install some requirements using pip for Odoo 11 and I need python3.5-dev also. I have tried the following and it results in error:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.5-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.5-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.5-dev'
```

I have also tried the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev
```

and results in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu, you can install it adding a PPA; so you can proceed in this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev
```

This solution is based on [Installing python 3.5 via apt-get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393054/installing-python-3-5-via-apt-get)

Comment: I am getting the following error on adding the repository:
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.